# Pause execution of a Javascript program

Tags: javascript, mobile

What's a clean way to 'halt' (or 'pause') execution of a code snippet in javascript, and resume execution (from the point it paused) when an external event occurs? The external event has to be propagated when a user does something, i.e. an event that is fired when the user clicks a button, touches a screen, etc

Ps: I am not looking for an infinite while loop. That's quite dirty and a CPU hugger.

This might make sense to you in the context of a mobile app.

Comment: like [firebug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_(software))?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  If you want that sort of effect, you typically hook up a callback to an event, and then trigger your code in response.

For instance, if you use jQuery and you want to alert "Hello World" when someone clicks a button, you don't do:

```
function alertHello() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
pause();
// some button gets clicked and you magically know to ...
alertHello();
```

You do:

```
function alertHello() {
    alert('Hello World');
}
$('#someButton').click(alertHello);
```